# Execute a command every minute?

Tags: pi-2

I need to execute this command:

```
/usr/sbin/ddclient -force
```

every minute, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to (as root) cron is probably what you are after

`sudo crontab -e`

then add the following

`* * * * * /usr/sbin/ddclient -force`

Comment: when I run `crontab -e` there are three options: `1. /bin/ed `, `2. /bin/nano`, `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`, I choosen `2` and then at the bottom I've added: `/usr/sbin/ddclient -force` but when I saved it: `CTRL + X`. This error message appear: `Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) y
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.NIZK9e/crontab":24: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)`

Comment: Those 5 asterisks are important they denote running the command every minute.

Comment: so 5 asterisks is equal to 60seconds?

Comment: The asterisks represent when the task will run, minute, hour, day of week, week of month, month of year. So if you set `1 * * * *` the task would run on the first minute of every hour of every day and so on. `* 1 * * 6` would only run at every minute of during 1 am of every day in June. Asterisk just means `match all`. There are a lot of much better explanations of `cron` out there though!